# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Error when calling method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use Laravel's Eloquent ORM via composer in a custom PHP framework I am building and I am getting an odd error when calling a create method in my controller.

**The Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.' in /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:763 Stack trace: #0 /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\Cont...', Array) #1 /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(130): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...') #2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors{closure}() #3 /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(964): call_user_func(Object(Closure)) #4 /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(832): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo() #5 /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(717): Illuminate\Database\Connection->rec in /Users/justin/Sites/test/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 763

**The Database Connection:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
$capsule = new Capsule();
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'database',
    'port' => '3306',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
]);
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

**The Model:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent{

    protected $fillable = ['username','email'];

}
```

**Finally the Method:**

```
public function create($username = '', $email = ''){
    User::create([
        'username' => $username,
        'email' => $email
    ]);
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: ```"illuminate/database": "^5.3"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Eloquent init may be incomplete.

The following is how I implemented it in a Silex app:

```
<?php
namespace App\Base\Provider\Database;

use Silex\Application;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class DatabaseSummoner
{
    public static function setup(Application $app)
    {
        $app['db'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
            # Set up Fluent Query Builder
            $capsule     = new Capsule;
            $db_settings = $app['config']['db'];

            $capsule->addConnection(
                $db_settings['connections'][$db_settings['connection']]
            );

            return $capsule;
        });

        // Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models...
        $app['db']->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

        // These two have to be outside closure
        // Make the Capsule instance available globally via static methods...
        $app['db']->setAsGlobal();
        // Boot Eloquent ORM
        $app['db']->bootEloquent();
    }
}
```

Then in my composer.json I require `"illuminate/database": "~5.3"` and `"illuminate/events": "~5.3"` (this second is optional, but useful if you want to use model events).

And, finally, in the `__construct()` of my `Application` class I call `DatabaseSummoner::setup($this);`.

This obviously differs from your setup, but you may find your way.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Realised I was using the incorrect version of Illuminate, needed to use 4.2

Comment: I wasted at least 2 days trying to figure out what is wrong it it... The latest version is totally broke. Thank you.